# Get number of placeholders in Formatter.format() String

Tags: java, string, string-formatting, formatter, string.format

In a Java program I am using a String with [`Formatter.format()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)) function, which I get from server. I cannot be sure that `String` to be formatted has placeholder or a valid number of them. If it the `String` is not as expected I would like to throw an exception - or log it somehow.

At this point I don't care of what type of placeholders are (`String`, `Integer`,...), I would just like to get number of expected parameters for each String.

What is the easiest way to achieve this? One way could be to use a regex, but I am thinking if there is something more convenient - a built in function for example.

Here are some examples:

```
Example String | number of placeholders:
%d of %d          | 2
This is my %s     | 1
A simple content. | 0
This is 100%      | 0
Hi! My name is %s and I have %d dogs and a %d cats. | 3
```

EDIT:
Formatter.format() throws an exception if there are not enough provided parameters. There is a possibility that I get a String without placeholders. In this case, even if I provide paramters (will be omitted), no exception will be thrown (eventhough I would like to throw one) only that String value will be returned. I need to report the error to server.

Comment: In what way can it be "not what you expect"? Presumably you know the number of placeholders you expect - can you just try formatting with default values, and see if it fails?

Comment: I don't know about a built in function, but my first thought is regex is the way to go.  Do you have any specific concerns about using regex?

Comment: @AndyTurner I was not clear enough. I know that format method throws an exception if I dont provide enough paramters. My problem is that I would like to throw an exception even if I provide too many parameters, that is why I would need the number of placeholders.

Comment: So, try formatting with all-but-one default values. If it fails, there are the correct number of placeholders; if is succeeds, there are too few placeholders.

Comment: @Hill Actually not really, but built in functions are tested on various cases, so writing my own regex may generate additional bugs. And I thought that this is a functionality it should have

Comment: @AndyTurner that is not really true. What if a provided String does not have a placeholder? format() will return this string, no exception will be thrown

Comment: You can take a look at the implementation of `String.format()`.

Comment: Well, it is true that it will throw an exception if you have at least one placeholder. You really need at least one in order to pass in all-but-one default values. And if there are zero placeholders, and you pass in zero default values, then it will succeed.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. I have checked the implementation of Formatter before, so it seems that regex is the way to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do it with a regular expression that defines the format of a placeholder to count the total amount of matches in your String.

```
// %[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision][t]conversion
String formatSpecifier
    = "%(\\d+\\$)?([-#+ 0,(\\<]*)?(\\d+)?(\\.\\d+)?([tT])?([a-zA-Z%])";
// The pattern that defines a placeholder
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(formatSpecifier);
// The String to test
String[] values = {
    "%d of %d",
    "This is my %s", 
    "A simple content.", 
    "This is 100%", "Hi! My name is %s and I have %d dogs and a %d cats."
};
// Iterate over the Strings to test
for (String value : values) {
    // Build the matcher for a given String
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(value);
    // Count the total amount of matches in the String
    int counter = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        counter++;
    }
    // Print the result
    System.out.printf("%s=%d%n", value, counter);
}
```

**Output:**

```
%d of %d=2
This is my %s=1
A simple content.=0
This is 100%=0
Hi! My name is %s and I have %d dogs and a %d cats.=3
```

Answer (score 3):

I have adapted the code of `String.format()`. Here is the result :

```
private static final String formatSpecifier
    = "%(\\d+\\$)?([-#+ 0,(\\<]*)?(\\d+)?(\\.\\d+)?([tT])?([a-zA-Z%])";

private static Pattern fsPattern = Pattern.compile(formatSpecifier);

private static int parse(String s) {
  int count = 0;
  Matcher m = fsPattern.matcher(s);
  for (int i = 0, len = s.length(); i < len; ) {
    if (m.find(i)) {
      // Anything between the start of the string and the beginning
      // of the format specifier is either fixed text or contains
      // an invalid format string.
      if (m.start() != i) {
        // Make sure we didn't miss any invalid format specifiers
        checkText(s, i, m.start());
        // Assume previous characters were fixed text
      }

      count++;
      i = m.end();
    } else {
      // No more valid format specifiers.  Check for possible invalid
      // format specifiers.
      checkText(s, i, len);
      // The rest of the string is fixed text
      break;
    }
  }
  return count;
}

private static void checkText(String s, int start, int end) {
  for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
    // Any '%' found in the region starts an invalid format specifier.
    if (s.charAt(i) == '%') {
      char c = (i == end - 1) ? '%' : s.charAt(i + 1);
      throw new UnknownFormatConversionException(String.valueOf(c));
    }
  }
}
```

Test :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(parse("Hello %s, My name is %s. I am %d years old."));
}
```

Output :

> 3