# Check if Android string resources has parameters

Tags: android, string

Is there a way to check if a string resource has parameters? So then if I have the following string in strings.xml:

```
   <string name="example1">Hey There!</string>
   <string name="example2">Hello %s</string>
```

I need a method that tells me that R.string.example2 has a parameter and that R.string.example1 hasn't got any.

Comment: I don't think so but you can use regular expressions 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413816/get-number-of-placeholders-in-formatter-format-string

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not very flexible and too simple but you can simply check whether it has `%s`:

```
public boolean hasParameter(String string) {
    return string.contains("%s");
}
```

And you can use it like that:

```
hasParameter(getString(R.string.example1));
```